# Do face-down creatures have "the same name" as each other?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has three face-down morphs on the battlefield.

I play [Sever the Bloodline](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=245194) targeting one of them.

Do we exile all three because they all have the "same name"? Or do we exile just one because "no name" indicates a lack of a characteristic altogether?

Comment: @user1872 this is a common question for players, and it's not obvious unless you read the comprehensive rules, something that not even the [Rules Manager recommed](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/179a&page=4) for most players (read the text about "What are the Comprehensive Rules?").

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Pablo, What happens when there are new loopholes in the rules found **during** tournys?  Who wins then and how does the game continue? Also, assuming in such an occasion we take "path A", and Tom wins the game. What happens if at a future date right after the tourny, an updated rulebook has been published to fix the mechanism flaws, and it states that we should have taken "path B" instead and John should have won the tourny?

Comment: @Pacerier In an official tournament, there are judges that resolve those kind of disputes. The relevant rules are the ones published when the tournament starts: future rules updates don't matter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They don't have names:

> 702.35a Morph is a static ability that functions in any zone from which you could play the card it’s on, and the morph effect works any time the card is face down. “Morph [cost]” means “You may cast this card as a 2/2 face-down creature, with no text, **no name**, no subtypes, no expansion symbol, and no mana cost by paying {3} rather than paying its mana cost.” (See rule 707, “Face-Down Spells and Permanents.”)

If they don't have names, they can't have the same name, so only the morph targeted by Sever the Bloodline will be exiled.

For an official source, see the fourth ruling in [Maelstrom Pulse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=180613):

> A face-down creature has no name, so it doesn't have the same name as anything else.

**Bonus:** *Why "no mana cost" gives us a converted mana cost of 0 instead of no converted mana cost?*: That's because there is a specific rule about this:

> 202.3a The converted mana cost of an object with no mana cost is 0.